# What is the difference in meaning between "be going to be doing something" and "will be doing something"?

Tags: difference, tense, future-tense

Is there any difference in meaning between *be going to be doing* and *will be doing*? For example:

> I can't go to the party as **I am going to be working** on my project.
>
> I can't go to the party as **I will be working** on my project.

Does the first sentence imply that the speaker had more agency in their decision making?

Comment: The first sentence doesn't sound right. Use either "will" or "I am working".

Comment: It may not sound correct, but that is what native English speakers say sometimes.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Yeah, your first sentence is fine.  The only weird thing is the question mark at the end, which I'm assuming is a typo.

Comment: Yes, it is a typo

Comment: They are both right. They mean the same thing, basically.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that the first sentence hints at a touch more agency.

The most idiomatic way to say this, in my opinion, would be:

> I can't go to the party because I'm working on my project.

"Going to be" here is implied but not stated; enough context is supplied to make this unambiguous.